# Invariant Violation: Tried to register two views with the same name RNCAndroidDropdownPicker

Tags: javascript, react-native

After importing and using the module react-native-picker:

```
import {Picker} from '@react-native-picker/picker';
 <Picker
    selectedValue={this.state.language}
    style={{height: 50, width: 100}}
    onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) =>
              this.setState({language: itemValue})
        }>
    <Picker.Item label="Java" value="java" />
    <Picker.Item label="JavaScript" value="js" />
 </Picker>
```

I get the following error:

```
Invariant Violation: Tried to register two views with the same name RNCAndroidDropdownPicker
```

What went wrong here?

Comment: Which version of `@react-native-picker/picker` you're using?

Comment: I am using the version 1.9.8

Comment: `react-native` version?

Comment: the react-native version is 0.63.3

Comment: I've run this on a new app which includes `1.9.8` and working fine with `react-native` 0.63.3. Can you share your `package.json`?

Comment: Yes: https://www.evernote.com/shard/s572/sh/b84d39e8-f38c-036d-de8a-decf91b2aafe/0bc7156a6decc628cf027c2544a05958

Comment: Check my updated answer below.

Comment: Yes, indeed it has

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To get rid of that, do the following:

Since the error is about registering two views with the same name, declare your `Picker` in this way:

```js
import { Picker as SelectPicker } from '@react-native-picker/picker';
```

instead of `import { Picker } from '@react-native-picker/picker';`

and implement like this:

```js
<SelectPicker
  selectedValue={this.state.language}
  style={{ height: 50, width: 100 }}
  onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) =>
    this.setState({ language: itemValue })
  }>
  <SelectPicker.Item label="Java" value="java" />
  <SelectPicker.Item label="JavaScript" value="js" />
</SelectPicker>
```

If the above solution doesn't work, do this

```sh
$ npm uninstall --save-dev @react-native-picker/picker
$ npm i @react-native-picker/picker --save
$ cd android
$ ./gradlew clean
$ cd ..
$ react-native run-android
```

**Update:**

This is the issue with `native-base`. Uninstall `native-base` and reinstall like this:

```sh
$ npm uninstall native-base --save
$ npm install native-base --save
```

[This issue](https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/pull/3230) has been fixed in the latest release of `native-base`.

Answer (score 4):

Just update `native-base` to the latest version and the error is resolved.

Answer (score 3):

you are getting this **Tried to register two views with the same name RNCAndroidDropdownPicker** issue because you have **`@react-native-community/datetimepicker`**
package is installed more than one in your node modules

I was also having this same problem and this following steps solved my issue

```
Remove this -> node_modules -> native-base -> node_modules -> @react-native-community/datetimepicker

Remove this -> node_modules -> react-native-weekly-calendar -> node_modules -> @react-native-community/datetimepicker
```

if still you are getting the same error than you also check for the library which contains the `@react-native-community/datetimepicker` package and you have to remove that because we have already installed it once in our node_modules and it will solve your problem

Answer (score 2):

**The cause of the problem for me**

An internal package used in the project had a dependency on `@react-native-community/picker`. And I was using `native-base:2.15.2`, which had a dependency on `@react-native-picker/picker`. So, there was a conflict between `@react-native-community/picker` and `@react-native-picker/picker`.

**How I found the cause**

Searched for `picker` in **package-lock.json** file and found two related packages given above.

**Solution**

I chose an older version of `native-base:2.13.12`, which had no dependency on `@react-native-picker/picker`.

**Why I decided to choose a different version of `native-base:`**

1. I could not replace the internal package.
2. I was not using `Picker` anywhere in the project directly.
3. Even if I used it, I could use the one provided by `@react-native-community/picker`.

I hope it provides better insight.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you have native-base imported and it has the Picker as a dependency, just use:

`import { Picker } from 'native-base';`

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had tried to use `Picker` directly from `React Native` but It said it had been moved. so I then installed another package called `react-native-picker-select`

After checking in my package-lock.json, I figured there were many Pickers there which could be the reason why it's confused so all I did was to :

*delete* my **`node_modules`** Folder, **stopped the server** and did **npm install** then re-run the server and it worked

Answer (score -1):

The issue is you might have multiple dependency with name 'Picker' in your react project.

To Identify the packages with same name try any one of the below way :

1. If you are using smart editor, try to remove the existing Picker dependency from import. and try auto reimport. You will see multiple Pickers like

- '@react-native-picker/picker'
- '@react-native-community/picker'
- 'native-base'

2. or search for picker in 'package.json' or 'package-lock.json'.

Once you find the dependency with the same name, make changes in your project to use only 1 dependency ( '@react-native-community/picker' and '@react-native-picker/picker' are almost same, so choose any one and you just have to update the dependency in import ), then use below command and uninstall the other dependency.

```
npm uninstall <<package_name>>
```

like npm uninstall @react-native-community/picker.

and rerun the project.